# Handle window's scroll bar's mouse move (WinAPI)

Tags: winapi, scrollbar

I have a window that has scroll bar styles so it has its own scrollbars. I want something to happen when the mouse hovers over the scroll bars, but handling the window's mouse move doesn't do the trick. How can I handle the scrollbars' mousemove event?

Thanks

Comment: Basically I'd like it to behave like when you have WS_SIZEBOX but only for the bottom and right, not top and left..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Win32 API, scrollbars have no 'mousemove event'. The only message you get from a vertical scrollbar is `WM_VSCROLL`.

If you want your scrollbars to have special behavior, you have to subclass them and override the handling of [Mouse Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa927364.aspx). As it says in MSDN ([Scroll Bar Controls in Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997557.aspx)):

> If, however, you wish to alter the
>   standard look or function of the
>   scroll bar, you can either subclass
>   the scroll bars on your window or
>   create a stand-alone control.

You can find examples of code which does this by by searching for 'subclass scrollbar'.

**Edit**

> What I'm trying to do is use the edge
>   of the scrollbar to make my sub window
>   resizable, is this possible?

The scrollbar is not the way to do it. Instead, define a window, a few pixels wide, just to the right of the scrollbar (and as tall). Set the cursor for that window to be a "resize" cursor (so the user will know to click and drag):

[image: resize cursors]

When that window gets a WM_LBUTTONDOWN message, it should start tracking the mouse, resizing and redrawing your control whenever the mouse moves. When the window gets WM_LBUTTONUP, it should stop tracking and leave your control at its new size.

[Here's some code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645602(v=VS.85).aspx#drawing_lines) that will get you started on the mouse-tracking functions. It's for drawing lines, but the process is similar.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is use the edge of the scrollbar to make my sub window resizable, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check if intercepting [WM_NCMOUSEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645627(VS.85).aspx) helps.

> The WM_NCMOUSEMOVE message is posted
>   to a window when the cursor is moved
>   within the nonclient area of the
>   window. This message is posted to the
>   window that contains the cursor. If a
>   window has captured the mouse, this
>   message is not posted.